# Export to Excel and PDF in PHP, Causing code redundancy

Tags: php, mysql, export, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I need to create export to excel and export to pdf option for some of my mysql queries and provide it to the user.

But also, the user needs to view the query results on my website too.

So, in this case, code redundancy occurs , as I have to create three php code files:

**One to let the user view the query results directly on my website** ,
 and,

**Other one to let the user export the same query results to Excel**  ,and ,

**last one to let the user export the same query results to PDF**

All the three files are having the same code, only the difference being the way of sending the data to excel or to pdf.

How do I eradicate this code duplicacy , Is there some way using which I could have only one file and use it for all purposes , to view , to export to pdf and to export to excel too.

Answer (score 3):

**"Is there some way using which I could have only one file and use it for all purposes , to view , to export to pdf and to export to excel too."** I think answer is YES.

You need to put a select box to give user option to view that particular code in a particular way. See below example code for that.

```
<select name="viewoption" id="viewoption">
<option value="view">Page view</option>
<option value="xls">Export in Excel</option>
<option value="pdf">Export in PDF</option>
</select>
```

and then on action page you just need to check out the value of `$_POST['viewoption']` and put **if condition** as per the requirements.

This may be helpful to you.let me know in case of any query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

as another commenter noted, you should split your functions. The way to handle it is the following

1) have one function that fetches your data from the database (this would be your model)

2) have another function that formats this data  (compute totals at end of rows or whatever) and also select which view to use (this would be your controller)

3) have another function that's specialised in SHOWING your data (so you'll have a view for PDF, one for XLS and another for web)

also, follow this advice from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030973/487891)

Answer (score 2):

Place all the code into one file. Use `$_GET['format']` to decide if you need to format as PDF or excel, default being the web page option, e.g.

```
<?php

if($_GET['format'] == "pdf")
{
     // export as PDF
}
elseif($_GET['format'] == "excel")
{
     // export as excel
}
```

Use hyperlinks to the same page as:

```
http://www.site.com/page.php?format=pdf
http://www.site.com/page.php?format=excel
http://www.site.com/page.php //webpage
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put it all in one file with answers given, but I'd say why would you do that? You probably have tons of other code floating around, or will eventually be floating around.

You should use a Model View Controller (MVC) design. You should have one class that handles all the sql (purely data and making sure data is accurately created, saved, returned), another file that takes/makes the requests for data and instructs which view to render, and lastly 2 or 3 template only type files (views) that simply format and render the data created in your controller.

Having more files/classes is better and makes your code more modular which eliminates code redundancy. Packing everything into one file increases code redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no redundancy here since you haven't written anything yet. The redundancy is in the ideas. With proper *abstraction* you can write code which is **DRY**. For example you can have a select like Chandersh provided above:

```
<select name="viewoption" id="viewoption">
<option value="view">Page view</option>
<option value="xls">Export in Excel</option>
<option value="pdf">Export in PDF</option>
</select>
```

Then you have to write some code - a controller if you will - which listens to the requests. Since you are writing out the same data but in different format you can do something like this:

1. **fetch data** (from the model if you will)
2. **decide** which function/code/view to run using the request
3. **call your function**/code/view which generates the proper format using your previous decision
4. done

I think that it *does not matter* whether you use MVC or not but the actual work what your components do together.

**Just a note:** having multiple files does not mean code duplication. Files are just containers. Take java for example. In java it is conventional to put every class to a different file.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate code is always a sign of *suboptimal* software design and there are many opportunities to prevent it. Here are some of them for your specific task:

**1. Use Params**

Unify your files into one and use GET-Params in your URL like `file.php?output=pfd`. In your script you can read in this parameter from `$_GET['output']` and decide, what export format to generate (`if ... else`, `switch`).

**2. Use Includes**

To have just one big file will be very confusing. So you can also keep your three php files and create a fourth file `get_data.inc.php`, where you have all the duplicate code fetching the data. Now you can load and execute this file in every of your three php's via `include get_data.inc.php`.

**3. Use Functions**

Outsourcing code into an include, maybe also confusing, because you have no idea, what the include will do and what are the dependencies. So it is better, to encapsulate the functionality into a function. Here you can clearly define, what to stick into the function (db connection?) and what you will get out (a data array?). Create a new file `get_data.func.php` and define a `function get_data($db_connection)`, doing all the stuff and returning the data ready to output. Then in every file include the file via `require_once get_data.func.php` and say `$Data = get_data($db_connection);`.

**4. Use Class Inheritance**

You can use the concept of class inheritance. You can define an abstract class, which includes the functionality to fetch your data from the database and you can define an abstract function `abstract public function output();`. Then you can create child classes extending your class, which are implementing the `output()` function in a specific way.

**5. Use a MVC Framework**

You could use an established framework, to implement a "Model View Controller" (MVC) pattern. Here you divide the different layers of your application (data from db, prepare data for output, present data) in a very clean way.

*Disclaimer: These are just some hints for learning, to better organize your projects. If you have not much experience, I do not suggest directly starting with a big MVC framework. Just take the path of enlightenment from top to down ;)*